# Is there a way to return function output on a html template in Python?

Tags: html, flask, python-3.7

I am using the below code :

```
def static_info(nm):
    cursor.execute("SELECT name,age,FROM MyDB where name like ?",(nm) + '%')
    for row in cursor:
        static={"NAME: ":row[0],"AGE: ":row[1]}
    return(static)

@app.route('/submit_form')
def submit_form():
    nm = request.form.get('name')
    info=static_info(nm)
    return render_template('static_display.html',info=info)
```

I need the desired function output (in the form of dictionary) on my static_display.html page

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange coding.

1. Your loop in `static_info(nm)` will only return the last item.  You're not appending anything
2. Your `@app.route('/submit_form')` does not accepts POSTs.  You need:

   @app.route('/submit_form', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
3. In your template `static_display.html`, you will want `{{ info }}`
4. If you change your code so you can loop over a list in your template, you will want something like:

   {% for item in info %}
   {% for key, value in item.items() %}
   {{ key }} : {{ value }}
   {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}